# Inserting repetitive star icons in HTML

Tags: html, image, alias

I am inserting repetitive star icons in HTML to display rating of hotels.

The problem is so many 'img' tags are used to represent hotel ratings.
It is not easy to modify because the source code length is getting long.

Can I make an alias for a long 'img' tag?

Or if anyone has a good solution, I'll be appreciated,
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fantastic tutorial - [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/)

From the article:

Demo - [Demo Link!](http://css-tricks.com/examples/StarRating/)

HTML

```
<div class="rating">
<span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.rating {
 unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
direction: rtl;
}
.rating > span {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 1.1em;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
content: "\2605";
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="first">
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#first {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
#second {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.img
{
background:url('http://www.letsgodigital.org/images/artikelen/35/nikon-d90-test-sample.jpg');
    width:250px;
    height:200px;
}
```

## [Fiddle..!!](http://jsfiddle.net/S2m7V/)